# How to set HTML5 type="date" input fields (e.g. in Chrome) using Selenium/Protractor?

Tags: html, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I want to update the date value (displayed as mm/dd/yyyy with only the number portions modifiable) of some HTML5 date form fields:

```
<input type="date"/>
```

in my Selenium/Protractor tests. I've tried using `sendKeys` for this but (on Chrome) have not been successful so far.

Is there a way to do this using `sendKeys`? Or some other way to do it?

Comment: Yes it is this fancy date field. If you have an approach you think will work please comment further about it.

Answer (score 8):

Using Chrome on Mac with Protractor, the following approach has worked for me.

Template (html5)

```
<input type="date" placeholder="Due Date" ng-model="newLesson.dueDate">
```

Test

```
this.newLessonDate = element( by.model('newLesson.dueDate') );
this.newLessonDate.sendKeys('01-30-2015');
```

I kept getting errors until I entered the date format as '01-30-2015'.

Comment: Thought I'd tried that but presumably I hadn't. Thanks.

Comment: I also needed to put the date in mm-dd-yyyy format to get SendKeys to work. According to the following link, the format the user sees in the box is “obtained from the operating system's setting.” When manually typing a date (or using SendKeys to simulate manual entry), it appears we need to use that format. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome

Answer (score 4):

Seems like the best approach at the moment is to update the input field without touching its UI representation.

For normal Selenium this approach appears to work (as the UI updates to match):

```
selenium.executeScript('document.getElementById("continuousFrom").value = "2050-01-01"');
selenium.executeScript('document.getElementById("continuousTo").value = "2050-01-14"');
```

My case is a bit more tricky because I'm using Angular and Protractor and the above approach didn't result in the model being changed. So I've ended up with this (even uglier) approach that modifies the model directly:

```
browser.waitForAngular();
browser.executeScript('var scope = angular.element($("#continuousFrom").get(0)).scope(); scope.dates.from = "2033-01-01"; scope.$apply();');
browser.executeScript('var scope = angular.element($("#continuousTo").get(0)).scope(); scope.dates.to = "2033-01-14"; scope.$apply();');
```

Also this is in a Protractor test and it took me a while to realise that the `executeScript` call does not wait for Angular to have finished creating the new DOM itself - hence the `waitForAngular` to make sure the ids are there.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue today, and I found the solution here http://www.guru99.com/handling-date-time-picker-using-selenium.html

The solution is to send only the date numbers, for example instead of sending "2015-06-12" you need to send "20150612".

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a working solution, use `Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString`:

```
// Remember that Date months are 0 based.
var keys = selenium.executeScript(
    'return (new Date(2016, 2, 7)).toLocaleDateString()'
);
sendKeys(keys);
```

Comment: Doesn't work with chrome. Date is broken: `2018-11-09` ends up as `11/09/1908`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a Credit Card expiry date with month and year only. The solution worked form me is using protractor.Key.TAB to move the cursor and input like below

`element(by.id('cc-expiry')).sendKeys('12', protractor.Key.TAB, '2019');`

So in your case you can try

`element(by.id('cc-expiry')).sendKeys('12', protractor.Key.TAB, '12', protractor.Key.TAB, '2019');`

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is meant to mimic user interaction and not setting attributes. 
However updating  the DOM elements by setting the type could be done using Javascript

```
document.getElementById("someID").setAttribute("type","date")
```

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't clear enough - I've updated it. It is the date value that the user enters that I need to update from Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where sendKeys() was working, but the input was always $invalid.  The only format that worked for me was 'YYYY-MM-DD' i.e. '2015-08-05'.  Any other variation on that format; slashes instead of hyphens, no delimiter, etc. remained invalid.

Even though I'm using Firefox version 37.0.2 which clearly supports HTML5 input type=date, It's noteworthy that [the docs say](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D):

"In browsers that do not yet support the HTML5 date input, a text element will be used. In that case, text must be entered in a valid ISO-8601 date format (yyyy-MM-dd), for example: 2009-01-06."

FWIW [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30806789/1991322) is the opposite of what worked for me.